# Cross domain XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a php file on a server, which just prints random numbers.

I want to get these numbers by using `XMLHttpRequest` from another domain.

How can I do this?

Comment: not clear .. do you want to send http request from php ? check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention, i want to send request from html file (actually for Google chrome extension), if i cant do this, is there any way to do ?

Comment: have you checked this http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: oh great, do i have to get it as only JSON ? cant i use just PHP ?
like this , xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.php", true);

Comment: there should not be any problem with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

XHR is subject to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). There is ongoing work to design and implement systems to allow cross-domain XHR, but the current state of those (the lack of browser support in particular) make it impractical for any real project.

The usual method to work around this is to implement the system using [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) instead of XHR.

Comment: i guess google chrome extensions allow cross-domain with the permission command as i want to send request from html file working in  google chrome.

Comment: yeah, I agree with David - JSONP, iframe or CSS hacks, or a proxy page (proxy.php?url=http://someurl) and then handler code on the .php side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery.ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **[`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** ([Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)) on your server.

The current versions of Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari support it now.

The next versions of Opera and Internet Explorer also support it but have not been released yet as of the beginning of March 2012.